# Регистрация через Google API

Tags: google-api

Добрый день! Подскажите, есть ли API для регистрации в Google?

Нужно регистрироваться на сайте и параллельно зарегистрироваться в Google — возможно ли такое?

Comment: Знаю, прошло уже 2 года. Но скажите, вы смогли реализовать это в итоге?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, так сделать нельзя. Регистрация это персональное действие, можно сказать даже интимное. В этом вопросе Google доверяет только лично пользователю.